# Angular smart table pagination fail with filtered objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using `angular-smart-table` for my tables in my application and I found a small issue using it:

Basically if I try to filter my Objects to exclude a few items containing a specified value the pagination fail showing less items per page and considering the total number of items as it wasn't filtered...

What I'm doing to filter is just this:

```
<tr ng:repeat="item in rowItems | filter: {name:'!Rick'} track by item.id">
```

And the result is visible in my fiddle: [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/qfpyu1kL/3/)

Comment: an alternative would be to `splice` items in the controller

Comment: Unfortunately I use the same collection for different tables and I need to filter values to show different data. Obviously, having more than 5000 items to show I can not create 20 different collections... The best solution for me is to filter my data in the HTML but keeping the `angular-smart-table` pagination updated...